# How to write function in SwiftUI that takes callback (function type) from user of the view so that user can chain the function calls?

Tags: swiftui

I am looking to expose functions from my struct that conforms to View protocol in such a way that user of struct can chain the function calls.

Below is what I wrote

```
struct MyResuableView: View {
    var event1Callback: () -> Void = {}
    var event2Callback: () -> Void = {}
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Resuable View")
    }
    
    mutating func onEvent1(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        self.event1Callback = action
        return self
    }

    mutating func onEvent2(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        self.event2Callback = action
        return self
    }
}
```

This is how I am looking to use it

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My View")
            MyResuableView()
                .onEvent1(action: self.event1Handler)
                .onEvent2(action: self.event2Handler)
        }
    }
    
    private func event1Handler() {
        
    }
    
    private func event2Handler() {
        
    }
}
```

I am getting below compilation error
***`Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value`*** which is understandable.

[image]

I looked at the thread [SwiftUI callback as parameter to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903607/swiftui-callback-as-parameter-to-a-view). This is one of the way to achieve but how to expose functions like onEvent1(....), onEvent2(....) to take functions as input from caller.

So I am just curious to know what do I need to (if we can) to achieve what I am looking for??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach (recalling that View is just a value)...

```
struct MyResuableView: View {
    var event1Callback: () -> Void = {}
    var event2Callback: () -> Void = {}
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Resuable View")
    }
    
    func onEvent1(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        var newOne = self
        newOne.event1Callback = action
        return newOne
    }

    func onEvent2(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        var newOne = self
        newOne.event2Callback = action
        return newOne
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could structure it the way view modifiers work.  Hand back a new view each time:

```
struct MyReusableView: View {
    let event1Callback: () -> Void
    let event2Callback: () -> Void
    
    init(event1Callback: @escaping () -> Void = {}, event2Callback: @escaping () -> Void = {})
    {
        self.event1Callback = event1Callback
        self.event2Callback = event2Callback
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Reusable View")
    }
    
    func onEvent1(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        .init(event1Callback: action, event2Callback: self.event2Callback)
    }

    func onEvent2(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        .init(event1Callback: self.event1Callback, event2Callback: action)
    }
}
```